# Thunderbird 7 with email notification indicator doesn't seems to work

Tags: 11.10, indicator, thunderbird, setup

I just realized that in Ubuntu 11.10 fresh install the message indicator menu doesn't notify me if I have new mail, just in case of starting Thunderbird. The email setup completed, when Thunderbird is running and downloading new email, the indicator works well.
But, when Thunderbird is not running, i thought the indicator checks for new email in the background without i need to start Thunderbird manually.
Checking for new emails is set for 1 minute period under settings menu (Thunderbird).
Is there something that i need to set for that checking period also applied for the indicator menu, or i'm missing something during the program setup, or is this a known bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a workaround, I use Popper from [Ralf Hersel's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ralf.hersel/+archive/rhersel-ppa) - it works nicely for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known „shortcoming”. There are several bugs filed in the tracking system related to this topic. E.g.:

1. [Minimize to Messaging Menu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/messagingmenu-extension/+bug/793838)
2. [Messaging menu TB extension disappears when TB is closed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/messagingmenu-extension/+bug/804918)

This is still under active development, you can keep an eye on the progress starting from the Mozilla Labs [Ubuntu Unity Messaging Menu page](http://mozillalabs.com/messaging/messaging-menu/).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it's good to know this feature is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

The indicator is part of Thunderbird. That means, if Thunderbird isn't running, it won't check for emails and therefore won't notify you of emails. It is not a bug, though it *may* be considered a missing feature.